# In a Windows 10 batch file, is there a way to extract only the last total files count?

Tags: file, batch-file, find

From a dir command that displays a number of sub-folders within a main folder, I am trying to extract the total number of files only. I am trying to use the FIND command with the string "File(s)", however this lists all of the file totals for each of the sub-folders, in addition to the overall total on the last line. I would like to limit my extraction to only this overall total, and none of the sub-folder file counts.

Comment: `dir /s /b /ad * |find /c /v ""`

Comment: `%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "MainFolder\*" "Null" /G/H/I/L/Q/R/S`

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I've provided a simple one liner already in the comment section, it does not technically provide a method of doing what you wanted. The task you've explained is really to retrieve a substring of the last but one line of output from the `DIR` command with its `/S` option. This method prevents the need to use the `FIND` command to search for the language dependent string `File(s)` too.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "MainFolder=C:\Users\CoastalGuy\Documents"
Set "CommandLine=Dir "%MainFolder%" /S /A:-D"

Set "Last="
Set "LastButOne="
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In (
    '%CommandLine% 2^>NUL'
) Do (
    If Defined Last (
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        For /F "Tokens=1 Delims= " %%H In ("!Last!") Do (
            EndLocal
            Set "LastButOne=%%H"
        )
    )
    Set "Last=%%G"
)
If Defined LastButOne (
    Echo %LastButOne%
    Pause
)
```

For the specific task you've posted, this script is a little over the top, but I've tried to create it more like a template, so that you could more easily adapt it for similar tasks, *(by changing the variable values on lines `4` and `5`, and modifying the `Tokens` and `Delims` values in the inner `For /F` loop as required)*.

Answer (score 0):

Found this simple result on an internet search:
After doing a dir /s of the main folder and then exporting a file (Files.txt) of each of the file results using FIND "File(s)", the following command extracts just the last line of that file, which has the grand total of Files from all sub-folders.....

For /F "UseBackQ Delims==" %%A In ("Files.txt") Do Set "lastline=%%A"
Echo - %lastline%

Works Great,
Thanks,